# Compiling a Java program to a Jar, works fine when run in Eclipse or Commandline but fails otherwise

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, build, imagej

Compiling a Java program to a Jar, works fine when run in Eclipse or commandline it even opens images when I click the open image button, it just never completes when I click process. The only way I can debug it is running it in commandline, but then it works fine. Really annoying no idea what to do.

Comment: So how do you expect your program to run? By double clicking the jar? Try this tutorial: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit597-2002/Pages/executable-jar-files.html

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem? It's pretty impossible to help you without knowing what the actual problem is.